# how to delete a file with symbols (Specifically the apostrophe)

Tags: html, sql, database, asp-classic

I have a database that stores teams. Each of these team names is unique. In the event that one is named Bob's Team. I have successfully managed to % encode the symbols when it is sent through the querystring to the next file. In this file I am getting an error with the SQL due to the apostrophe and I don't know how to fix it. Not quite sure about all this escaping stuff I'm reading. It's pretty confusing. Here is the line causing the problem:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Teams WHERE TeamName='" & TheTeamName & "'"
```

In the event that Bob's Team is the name of the team. The error I get is:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'TeamName='Bob's Team''.

/DeleteTeam.asp, line 35
```

I'd like to know what I have to do in order to make it properly delete a team with an apostrophe (and possibly other annoying symbols) in it.

Comment: Learn about [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Welcome to SQL Injection (sorta).  Use parameterized queries.

Comment: This paramatized thing is completely new to me. I'm going to go delving into it, but it would be nice if somebody could provide a quick explanation w/ maybe an applicable code sample or a link to a good site that does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your query work as is you can try the following:

Replace in TheTeamName the Single Quote ' by ''
Then use it in your query. (@least this works in MySQL not sure abt your DB engine but give it a try).

Note that it is better to use prepared statement to prevent SQL-Injection

Comment: Timewise learning that by tonight isn't very feasible so I'm going to try this for now. If you don't mind, could you show me where in the code specifically you are referring too? Are you suggesting to have it as Bob''s Team instead?

Comment: Correct, you will change Bob's Team to Bob''s Team. (Of Course this would be done programmatically by replacing in the String TheTeamName  the Single quote ' by two '').

Comment: LOL I can't ask any more questions for 2 days. It's quite a while since my last and only previous 2 questions.